# Creating a loop function for a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I have a list of data frames which I created by using the split() function

```
new<-split(dfall1, dfall1$plotid)
str(new)
```

It gives me a list of 27 df as tibbles:

```
 $ 110: tibble [76 x 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ pinTemp            : num [1:76] 7.31 7.55 7.4 7.34 7.13 ...
  ..$ surfaceTemp        : num [1:76] 8.7 8.47 8.11 7.93 7.43 ...
  ..$ airTemp            : num [1:76] 8.03 7.42 6.87 6.89 6.55 ...
  ..$ pin_delta          : num [1:76] -0.0968 -0.1123 -0.1677 -0.3257 -0.2773 ...
  ..$ surface_delta      : num [1:76] 0.105 0.172 0.25 0.291 0.241 ...
  ..$ air_delta          : num [1:76] 0.12433 0.00724 0.04134 0.04762 0.00669 ...
  ..$ timeflooded        : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ elevation_nhn      : num [1:76] 153 153 153 153 153 ...
  ..$ strand_nhn         : num [1:76] -8.79 41.49 2.93 NA -6.65 ...
  ..$ plot_waterlevel_nhn: num [1:76] -162 -111 -150 NA -159 ...
  ..$ plot_flood_nhn     : num [1:76] 0 0.275 0.15 NA 0.0417 ...
  ..$ plot_timeflooded   : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ plotid             : Factor w/ 27 levels "110","111","112",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ zone               : Factor w/ 3 levels "HM","LM","PIO": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ yday               : int [1:76] 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 ...
 $ 111: tibble [76 x 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ pinTemp            : num [1:76] 9.68 9.94 9.54 9.14 8.67 ...
  ..$ surfaceTemp        : num [1:76] 10.05 9.73 9.24 8.99 8.57 ...
  ..$ airTemp            : num [1:76] 7.82 7.31 6.77 6.73 6.39 ...
  ..$ pin_delta          : num [1:76] 2.27 2.27 1.97 1.55 1.27 ...
  ..$ surface_delta      : num [1:76] 1.46 1.36 1.39 1.34 1.39 ...
  ..$ air_delta          : num [1:76] -0.0981 -0.1079 -0.0601 -0.1219 -0.1571 ...
  ..$ timeflooded        : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ elevation_nhn      : num [1:76] 152 152 152 152 152 ...
  ..$ strand_nhn         : num [1:76] -8.79 41.49 2.93 NA -6.65 ...
  ..$ plot_waterlevel_nhn: num [1:76] -160 -110 -149 NA -158 ...
  ..$ plot_flood_nhn     : num [1:76] 0 0.275 0.15 NA 0.0625 ...
  ..$ plot_timeflooded   : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ plotid             : Factor w/ 27 levels "110","111","112",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ zone               : Factor w/ 3 levels "HM","LM","PIO": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ yday               : int [1:76] 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 ...
 $ 112: tibble [76 x 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ pinTemp            : num [1:76] 8.52 9.02 9.1 9.16 9.11 ...
  ..$ surfaceTemp        : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA 8.56 ...
  ..$ airTemp            : num [1:76] 7.86 7.39 6.76 6.78 6.52 ...
  ..$ pin_delta          : num [1:76] 1.11 1.36 1.53 1.49 1.7 ...
  ..$ surface_delta      : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA 0.887 ...
  ..$ air_delta          : num [1:76] -0.0547 -0.0296 -0.0706 -0.0636 -0.017 ...
  ..$ timeflooded        : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ elevation_nhn      : num [1:76] 149 149 149 149 149 ...
  ..$ strand_nhn         : num [1:76] -8.79 41.49 2.93 NA -6.65 ...
  ..$ plot_waterlevel_nhn: num [1:76] -157 -107 -146 NA -155 ...
  ..$ plot_flood_nhn     : num [1:76] 0 0.3 0.175 NA 0.0625 ...
  ..$ plot_timeflooded   : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ plotid             : Factor w/ 27 levels "110","111","112",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ zone               : Factor w/ 3 levels "HM","LM","PIO": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ yday               : int [1:76] 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 ...
 $ 120: tibble [76 x 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ pinTemp            : num [1:76] 9.96 9.5 9.98 9.82 9.66 ...
  ..$ surfaceTemp        : num [1:76] 9.12 8.61 8.1 7.86 7.26 ...
  ..$ airTemp            : num [1:76] 7.93 7.47 6.87 6.85 6.54 ...
  ..$ pin_delta          : num [1:76] 1.67 1.43 1.71 1.61 1.73 ...
  ..$ surface_delta      : num [1:76] 0.448 0.237 0.214 0.204 0.061 ...
  ..$ air_delta          : num [1:76] 0.01845 0.05104 0.04443 -0.00231 -0.0044 ...
  ..$ timeflooded        : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ elevation_nhn      : num [1:76] 152 152 152 152 152 ...
  ..$ strand_nhn         : num [1:76] -8.79 41.49 2.93 NA -6.65 ...
  ..$ plot_waterlevel_nhn: num [1:76] -161 -111 -150 NA -159 ...
  ..$ plot_flood_nhn     : num [1:76] 0 0.275 0.15 NA 0.0417 ...
  ..$ plot_timeflooded   : num [1:76] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ plotid             : Factor w/ 27 levels "110","111","112",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ zone               : Factor w/ 3 levels "HM","LM","PIO": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ yday               : int [1:76] 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 ...
```

etc.
I want to apply a loop function to create new data frames with average values for a week. This function works, if I am applying it to one dataframe alone but not if I am trying to do it for all at once:This is what I have tried so far

```
newdf<-new %>% group_by(Week = floor_date(time1-4, unit="week")) %>% 
  summarize(weeklyAvsoilT=mean(pinTemp,na.rm=T),weeklyminsoilT=min(pinTemp,na.rm=T),weeklymaxsoilT=max(pinTemp,na.rm=T),
            weeklyAvsurfT=mean(surfaceTemp,na.rm=T),weeklyminsurfT=min(surfaceTemp,na.rm=T),
            weeklymaxsurfT=max(surfaceTemp,na.rm=T),weeklyAvairT=mean(airTemp,na.rm=T),
            weeklyminairT=min(airTemp,na.rm=T),weeklymaxairT=max(airTemp,na.rm=T), 
            min_date = min(time1), max_date = max(time1)) %>% mutate(weekdays(min_date), weekdays(max_date))
```

it gives me the error

```
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "list"
```

but I don´t know, how to change the list of df into just df´s.
I also thought about using lapply() but then I was not sure how the syntax works for this particular case. Because I am actually trying to create shorter df out of these longer ones.
I could of course use the same code and repeat it 27 times, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: When you use `split()` your output is a list. You need a data frame. So instead of splitting, just add the `plotid` in your `group_by()` statement

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry  I forgot to mention that I already tried that too. It did not work. Maybe I did the syntax wrong. ```newdfall1done<-dfall1%>% group_by(plotid, .add=TRUE)%>%group_by(Week = floor_date(time1sdone-4, unit="week")) %>% ``` like this, but it did not work.

Comment: Put both in one `group_by()`, i.e. `group_by(plotid, week = floor_date(time1sdone-4, unit="week"))`

Comment: Now I get at least the correct values for most of my variables. Only the week start and end is not working. But this is only a minor issue. thanks for your help!